# What are the typical gate times for single-qubit and 2-qubit gates for ion trap, superconducting, neutral atom, photonic, spin QC?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, entanglement, error-correction, experimental-realization

What are the typical gate times  for single-qubit and 2-qubit gates for

-- ion trap,

-- superconducting,

-- neutral atom,

-- photonic,

-- spin

quantum computers based on today's technologies?

Comment: different technologies might result in entirely different answers. This sort of thing is better covered by asking individual questions focusing on each technology, imo

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the reliability of this site and these authors: [The Next Decade in Quantum Computing—and How to Play 2018 Philipp Gerbert and Frank Ruess](https://www.bcg.com/publications/2018/next-decade-quantum-computing-how-play)

In the article they provide an extensive summary (2018) of the different technologies and gate fidelities, see exhibit 7:
[image]

Comment: It would be nice if anyone can compile a similar list for the state of art at the year end of 2021.